# How to correctly prevent access to php page to users which are not logged in

Tags: php, html, mysql

I managed to develop a login page (index.php) which correctly redirects to another php page (welcome.php).
My goal is to prevent users to access welcome.php page if not logged in.

I already followed suggestions of other users, here's part of code:

Index.php

```
<?php
    include("settings/dbConfig.php");
    if (!isset($_SESSION))
        session_start();
    if($_SESSION['login_user'])
        header("location: php/welcome.php");

    if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // username and password sent from form 


$myemail = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['email']);
    $mypassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$_POST['pass']); 

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE email = '$myemail' and password = md5('$mypassword');";
    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);


 $active = $row['active'];
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);



// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1
            if($count == 1) {
                $_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;
                header("location: php/welcome.php");
            }
            else {
                    $error = "Login Failed... Please retry";
                }
            }
    ?>
```

Welcome.php

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(!isset($_SESSION['login_user'])){
        header("location: logout.php");
        die();
    }
?>
```

Login works good, if I try to access welcome.php page without having logged in I get immediately redirected to index.php page and that's good too.

Problem is: I get redirected to index.php even if I correctly log in with valid credentials.
I expect to be redirected back to `index.php` only if I'm not logged in and to be redirected to `welcome.php` if I'm logged in.
How should I modify provided code in order to achieve that?

Comment: `session_start()` should always be on most top of your script - by the wy ... do not use md5() to hash passwords - php offers good built in functions for this

Comment: You shouldn't use md5() for passwords, you should use password_hash and password_verify. You should use prepared statements because you are open to SQL injections

Comment: You are ending one PHP script and load another. Better use [session_write_close()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-write-close.php) just to be sure the `login_user` is saved. But this is probably not your problem. Did you close the browser? That would have killed the session. Check your [session_get_cookie_params()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-get-cookie-params.php) lifetime setting.

Comment: ***You really shouldn't use [MD5 password hashes](http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19906/is-md5-considered-insecure)*** and you really should use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. Make sure  you [don't escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527) or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: how you can get `$row['active']` if you are getting the only `id` from your query?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
<?php
    session_start();
    if(isset($_SESSION['login_user']))
        header("location: php/welcome.php");
    else
        header("location: php/index.php");
?>
```

This might be a solution, but you better learn about prepared statements and PHP built-in functions for security reasons as suggested in comments.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I put into practice your suggestion and nothing changed. 
After some echo I put in some places in code I found out $_SESSION['login_user'] is always empty for some reason, even after correctly logging in.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to solve problem, was easier than expected.
Issue was on line : `$_SESSION['login_user'] = $myusername;`
Since `$myusername` doesn't exists, of course session variable won't exist too.